# When is it OK to free a root in the shadow-stack?

Tags: garbage-collection, llvm

When looping through the roots registered by the LLVM shadow-stack, is it OK to free them? Or is the root list only a list of the roots that are *alive*? In which case I need a separate list of *all* mallocs, not only the ones in the roots.